# import Qt ui to Maya2020

Tags: python-2.7, qt, maya, pyside2, shiboken2

Last week I started learning Python for Maya, following the 'CGCircuit - Learn Python Inside Maya'.
Now I'm trying to make a simple UI for Maya2020 using Qt. The tutorial itself is pretty outdated, a lot has changed since Maya2015.
I checked a lot of forums and it seems I’m not the only one having problems. This is what I learned so far:

- Qt designer is not a part of Maya anymore, so I downloaded Qt Creator 4.14.0 (Community)
- I used pip to install: shiboken2-5.15.2-5.15.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-none-win_amd64.whl
- If I'm correct, Maya2020 has Pyside2 pr-installed, but I also Installed Pyside2 on Windows10
- QtGui.QDialog is replaced by QWidget
  Currently I ‘m using Python 2.7.17 on my Windows system, but I also have Python3.8 available in my Environment Variable

When I call the py script inside Maya, like this:

```
import geomGenerator
reload(geomGenerator)
geomGenerator.getMayaWindow()

geomGenerator.run()
```

I get this error:

```
 Error: NameError: file C:/Users/12213119/Documents/maya/2020/scripts\geomGenerator.py line 12: global name 'shiboken2' is not defined #
```

Not sure what this means or how I can solve it. I looked all over the internet, please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thx in regard.

```
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore, QtUiTools, QtWidgets
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance

import maya.cmds as mc
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

def getMayaWindow():
    """ pointer to the maya main window  
    """
    ptr = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken2.wrapInstance2(long(ptr), QtWidgets.QWidget)


def run():
    """  builds our UI
    """
    global win
    win = GeometryGenerator(parent=getMayaWindow())
    win.show()

class GeometryGenerator(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(GeometryGenerator,self).__init__(parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to run you script with python that comes with Maya, and use pip that comes with maya to install packages.